# MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms. How do I resolve this?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

Error:

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\Web Dev\Traversy\storybooks\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:153:23)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

GET /auth/google/callback?code=4%2F0ARtbsJqsdI35M7-9iSldOa1xWXs9SXFW09MohqzZ94_K5I5jpc1YTKge6lGKuS8-jPRyZA&scope=profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile - - ms - -

What I tried to do:
mongoose.connect(...) code is loading except this is my code where I tried to comment out: useFindAndModify: true

db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            // useFindAndModify: true
        })
        console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`)
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err)
        process.exit(1)
    }
}
module.exports = connectDB
```

auth.js

```
const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport')
const router = express.Router()
// @desc    Auth with Google
// @route   GET /auth/google
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }))
// @desc    Google auth callback
// @route   GET /auth/google/callback
router.get('/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
    })
module.exports = router
```

passport.js

```
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('../models/User')
module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
    },
        async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
            // console.log(profile)
            const newUser = {
                googleId: profile.id,
                displayName: profile.displayName,
                firstName: profile.name.givenName,
                lastName: profile.name.familyName,
                image: profile.photos[0].value
            }
            try {
                let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id })
                if (user) {
                    done(null, user)
                } else {
                    user = await User.create(newUser)
                    done(null, user)
                }
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err)
            }
        }))
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id, (err, user) => done(err, user))
    })
}
```

App.js

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const passport = require('passport')
const session = require('express-session')
const connectDB = require('./config/db')

// Load config
dotenv.config({ path: './config/config.env' })

// Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport)

connectDB()

const app = express()

// Logging
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'))
}

// Handlebars (Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars)
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs.engine({ defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs' }))
app.set('view engine', '.hbs')

// Sessions
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/index'))
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/auth'))




const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: It's unclear to me how you are using `connectDB`/`db.js` elsewhere (eg in `passport.js`). Additionally, that first file seems to have `const conn = ...` declared inside of the function - is it usable elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. I've required connectDB in the App.js from db.js.